# Network Manager needs to be running

Tags: network-manager, sudo, proxy

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS installed in my machine. I am behind a proxy server(in college) and I am facing a problem after I have started using proxy. The problem is : The Network manager gets stopped automatically. I have attached screenshots as well.

This problem has already happened with others before and people have suggested to restart NetworkManager.service, but I can't do so as I can't run any 'sudo' command once this problem is started(ssht attached). I even tried to restart using "/etc/init.d/network-manager restart", but this doesn't work as well. I have already reinstalled Ubuntu(even deleted all partition as well), this doesn't worked as well.

The only option left is restarting my machine which doesn't get shut down in the regular way, so I have to shut it down using power button.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Looking forward for some help.

I have uploaded logs of kernel and Network manager in the drive. Attached is the link to it.

[Logs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MCwYJf11WvJAtlXnWOi_P2cQs8M-T6Mv?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello. Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. As you can see in your own pictures info is cut off to the right so the picture may not be of any help missing info.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I have the same problem and solution on internet does not work.

Comment: I think yes. I tried understanding logs but nothing seem to work. But after I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I haven't faced any such problem.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the network manager by using the below command worked for me:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: For me, I had to use "NetworkManager" instead. Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` works for me

Answer (score 2):

Run the command `sudo service NetworkManager restart` on your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

> The Network manager gets stopped automatically

"automatically" can mean either:

- you have some software that stops NetworkManager. You apparently don't want that, so stop that software from doing that.
- NetworkManager crashes. That is a bug, and the right solution is to fix it (or at least find a workaround).

In any case, check the logs in `journalctl` to see what happens. Try also `journalctl -u NetworkManager` to only see logs from NetworkManager.

> people have suggested to restart NetworkManager.service

If it's stopped you probably want to restart the service. But it would be better to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First check the logs of NetworkManager and the kernel.

- journalctl -u NetworkManager.service
- dmesg

Comment: Please have a look at the logs, link added above.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, I slove this problem by reinstall network-manger

```
$ sudo apt install network-manger
.....
Ign:1 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libndp0 amd64 1.8-0ubuntu3
Ign:2 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libteamdctl0 amd64 1.31-1build2
Ign:3 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 network-manager amd64 1.36.6-0ubuntu2
Ign:4 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ppp amd64 2.4.9-1+1ubuntu3
Ign:5 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 pptp-linux amd64 1.10.0-1build3
Ign:6 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 network-manager-pptp amd64 1.2.10-1
....
```

so, we need install libndp0,libteamdctl0,network-manager,ppp,pptp-linux,network-manager-pptp

```
PS C:\Users\CFM880\Downloads\network-manager> ls

    Directory: C:\Users\CFM880\Downloads\network-manager

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           2022/8/23    15:59          12328 libndp0_1.8-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    16:12         456582 libnm0_1.36.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    16:03          90974 libteam-utils_1.31-1build2_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    16:13          25170 libteam5_1.31-1build2_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    16:03          12558 libteamdctl0_1.31-1build2_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    15:56        2200304 network-manager_1.36.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    16:01          30940 network-manager-pptp_1.2.10-1_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    16:00         362856 ppp_2.4.9-1+1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
-a---           2022/8/23    16:00          42504 pptp-linux_1.10.0-1build3_amd64.deb
```

You can search packages(libndp0,libteamdctl0,network-manager,ppp,pptp-linux,network-manager-pptp) at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and download

then install

```
cd download path
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

reboot computer