# Network Manager keeps crashing

Tags: networking, network-manager

When I manually try to turn off my WiFi or switch network from the system tray, NetworkManager crashes and I get this [NetworkManager needs to be running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN8ym.png)

I followed a solution from here [Ask Ubuntu | NetworkManager needs to be running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402589/network-manager-needs-to-be-running) but when I try to run any of the commands like `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` my system freezes and I have to press and hold the power button to power off.

Here are my system specs.

[image: system specs]